# WAZE for web is not responding to register, why?

Tags: events, click, onclick, openlayers

I am trying to make waze react and send me back lat,lon coordinates upon click.
I managed to do this with OpenLayers, but waze doesn't respond. 
I don't know if the event has been registered or not even, and if it did, maybe the mouse don't fire the event... How can I find out ?

Here's the code snippet:

```
function onInit(){
var map = g_waze_map.map;

// MY STUFF
controls = {
                point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                            OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
                drag: new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors)
            };

for(var key in controls) {
    map.addControl(controls[key]);
}

size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);
markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );

map.addLayer(markers);

map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {

    var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
//          alert(position.lon.toFixed(3) + ', ' + position.lat.toFixed(3));

alert("Mouse click");
});
```

}

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the Waze API does but you can achieve the same thing using the [MousePosition](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/MousePosition-js.html) control.
Just add it an instance of it to the map and it shows the current lonlat on top of the map.

**EDIT:** It looks your `onInit` function which registers the click callback never gets called. Your script has two `g_waze_config` variables, the one which contains a reference to the `onInit`function is declared only after the Waze script is included, causing it not to get called.

Comment: I need to be able to intercept clicks. Upon a click I want to place a marker on the map

Comment: do you have this webapp hosted somewhere so that one can see other code? it can be any other code/library on the page intercepting events.

Comment: Sure:  Here's the waze irresponsive code: [link](http://showreel2009.com/maps/waze_test.html)    and here's openLayers clickable map code:[link](http://showreel2009.com/maps/openLayers_test.html)

Comment: There obviously has to be something going on inside the file : [http://www.waze.co.il/js/WazeEmbeddedMap.js](http://www.waze.co.il/js/WazeEmbeddedMap.js) I am not sure of how I should approach this.